# Gitcola says "you must stage at least 1 file before you can commit"

Tags: git, commit, git-commit, git-clone

Although I have made changes to the folder of the repository I cloned, somewhy I cannot commit..

Comment: Sounds like you haven't staged your changes. In Git, you stage changes first, then commit your staged changes. Many Git tools let you just commit all changes without staging first, but they're just staging it behind the scenes for you. Sounds like Gitcola doesn't do that.

Comment: Did you perform 'git add' on changed files?

Comment: It's time to read at least a (very) short tutorial about git...

Answer (score 1):

Basics of committing:

`git status` - shows you the status of the repo, including unstaged files.

`git add <filename>` stages that file.

`git add --all` stages all files.

`git commit` starts a commit.

`git commit -m "message"` is a one-liner for a commit

`git commit -a` commits all files

`git push <remote> <branch>` pushes a branch and its commits to a remote refspec, e.g. `git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Does it say 'no changes added to commit'?

If that's the case, you have to manually add the files that you want to commit first. Use:

```
git add <filename>
```

Where *filename* is the file where you made your changes. For example:

```
git add aFolder/source/file.txt
```

Then you'll be able to commit.